# remove frontispiece and frontispieceimagepath

Tags: diagrams, templates, thesis

I am using this template 
[Customizable Thesis Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/customizable-thesis-template-pdflatex-english/rdjdtrckcjzw#.Wln3w9x948o)

I would like to remove the picture entitled "aesop" on the second page.

If I remove line 242

```
\setFrontispiece[0.8]{figures/aesop.png}{Aesop}
```

I get

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \frontispieceimagepath 

l.256
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You have to remove also the `frontispiece' option. So remove line 241 and write `\documentclass[modern,hyperref,watermark,histinit,minitoc]{teipel-thesis-en}` instead of `\documentclass[modern,hyperref,watermark,histinit,frontispiece,minitoc]{teipel-thesis-en}`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `frontispiece` option from the `\documentclass` declaration (line 49):

```
\documentclass[modern,hyperref,watermark,histinit,minitoc]{teipel-thesis-en}
```